# Return a list of people that have only car, motorbike or car and motorbike

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1

Name, Vehicle
P1, Car
P1, Motorcylce
P1, Truck
P1, Helicopter
P2, Car
P3, Motorcycle
P4, Motorcycle
P4, Car
P5, Car
P5, Truck
P6, Motorcycle
P6, Truck
P7 Truck
```

How do I query the table above so that only people with with either have a car, or a motorbike or must have both the car and the motorbike are returned.

So
only,

```
P2 -> only has a car (valid)
P3 -> only has a motorcyle (valid)
P4 -> has both car and motorcycle (valid)
```

are returned

Comment: Is the number of cars important? I have two cars, but no motorcycle, truck or helicopter - am I in or out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with `conditional aggregation`:

```
select name
from yourtable
group by name
having count(case when vehicle = 'Car' then 1
                  when vehicle = 'Motorcycle' then 1
             end) = count(*)
```

- [Sample Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ej4fM8GptBk9FvGJC8AkUH/0)

If you can have people with more than one car or motorcycle that you don't want to be returned (i.e. P8 has 2 cars), use `count(distinct vehicle)`  instead to exclude those records.  Not clear with your posting if that matters or not.

Comment: why count(*) in the end?

Comment: It's how you can compare the count of all vehicles (`count(*)`) per `name` to the count of those vehicles that are only car or motorcycle.  If the count is greater than just car or motorcycle, then the name won't be returned.

Comment: Running this in mysql gives me an error, vehicle is not a valid column....

Comment: @Vish -- did you look at the sample demo?  you may need to post your actual table definition if the column name isn't `vehicle`...

Comment: I am using your table definition. It works on that website, but not on my server....

Comment: [SQL]SELECT
vlog.lead_id, vlog.phone_number
FROM
vicidial_log as vlog
GROUP BY vlog.lead_id
HAVING(
CASE 
WHEN vlog.status = 'NA' THEN 1 
WHEN vlog.status = 'ADC' THEN 1 
END
) = COUNT(*)

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'vlog.status' in 'having clause'

Comment: @Vish -- You removed the `count` aggregate.   It should be `... having count(case ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173579/discussion-between-vish-and-sgeddes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
select Name from table 
where Name  not in (select distinct Name from table where Vehicle in 
('Helicopter','Truck'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Return people `EXCEPT` those having a type of vehicle that is not a car or a motorcycle.

```
select name from tablename
except
select name from tablename where vehicle not in ('Car', 'Motorcycle')
```

An extra `WHERE` clause may speed things up:

```
select name from tablename where vehicle in ('Car', 'Motorcycle')
except
select name from tablename where vehicle not in ('Car', 'Motorcycle')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select name
from yourtable
where vehicle in ('car', 'motorbike')
group by name
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that there is only one row per type.  If not, use `count(distinct)`:

```
select name
from yourtable
where vehicle in ('car', 'motorbike')
group by name
having count(distinct vehicle) = 2;
```

Comment: As I understand the question, people having a helicopter or a truck should never be returned, even if they have car and/or motorcycle.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.name = t.name and 
                        t1.Vehicle in ('Helicopter', 'Truck')
                 );
```